# IIS Default Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have an IIS configuration such that [mywebapp] is an asp.net mvc web app that exists under "Default Web Site" of myserver.com.

How do I configure my IIS so that a request to www.myserver.com actually displays the home page of [mywebapp], without changing the url to www.myserver.com/mywebapp.  Currently the url change is what happens as I am using HttpRedirect on Default Web Site, but this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a DNS record set that maps your server IP address to the domain name, you will need to set up a new site, rather than a virtual directory underneath Default website. When you create the site, enter your domain name in the `Host name` field.

You can test this configuration locally first by setting the site up in IIS and then adding an entry in your hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) that maps the domain name to your localhost IP address `127.0.0.1` - just remember to remove that once you're happy with the setup or you won't actually be hitting the live IP address.

Comment: ok I created a new site, set the site name to [myweb] with physical path c:\inetpub\[myweb], and set the host name to [mywebsite.com].  Then I published my app from visual studio to [www.mywebsite.com].  Now, in IIS, the [myweb] site has a virtual directory under it called [mywebapp].  I still have to use [mywebsite.com]\[mywebapp] to get to it though.  I want to get to it by [mywebsite.com] instead.  What have I missed?

Comment: Is this all on the same machine? I think you can publish to a file system location using visual studio rather than a URL. If you can do that, then you can configure IIS manually to point the site at that physical folder

Comment: ok got it...in the VS Publish Wizard, I had to put [myweb] in the site/app field, as opposed to [myweb]/[mywebapp].